# Can a Python script activate a virtual environment and then trigger an interactive pdb session within it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb, python-venv

On my Linux machine, I can activate the virtual environment and start an interactive debugging session with following bash commands -

```
source ~/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/activate
python -m pdb ~/python_project/testscript.py
```

Could a python script achieve the same?

The first command `source ~/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/activate` fails when  I tried to execute it in a subshell possibly because `source` is a bash builtin -

```
>>> os.system("source pytorch-3.7-env/bin/activate")
sh: 1: source: not found
32512
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can but there's no reason to: you can just call the virtualenv's python directly  (`~/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/python`) and it'll execute in the correct environment. You don't *need* to activate envs in a non-interactive environment.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use :

```
#! ~/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/python
```

at the top of your file.

or
you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):  to execute the command

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(". .FULL_PATH/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/python")
```

Comment: I received an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source': 'source'`

Comment: `source ~/pytorch-3.7-env/bin/activate` changes some environmental variables. If we skip this step, could it impact the interactive pdb session?